# How can I find a line in a text file and replace it?

Tags: c++, c++11, file-handling

I'm working on a project for university which requires me to find a value in a text file and replace it with a new value that I have stored in a float variable, part of the problem is that I do not know the item that needs to be replaced, only where it is (e.g. I could search for a value of 0.00 but multiple records could have that balance).

The text file is laid out like so:

> Username1
>   Password1
>   AccountNo1
>   Balance1
>   Jimmy54
>   FooBar123
>   098335
>   13.37
>   ...

And the relevant part of my code looks like this:

User enters their username and we store it in enteredName

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    cout << "Please enter your username:\n";
    cin >> enteredName;
```

About 100 lines down in the code we get to the part important to this question:

```
        if (c2 == 1)
        {
            //irrelevant to problem
        }
        else if (c2 == 2) 
        {
            float convBal;
            float deposit;
            string newBal;

            convBal = ::atof(ball.c_str()); 

             /* Ball is declared higher up in the code and just contains a 
                value pulled from the text file for the sake of the question 
                we'll say it has a value of 0.00 */

            cout << "How much would you like to deposit?:\n";
            cin >> deposit;

            newBal= convBal + deposit;

            cout << "Your total balance is now: "<< newBal << "\n\n";

        } 
}
```

So what needs to be done from here is open the file, search the file for enteredName (in this case we'll say Jimmy54) and then replace the value 3 lines below the username (13.37) with the value stored in newBal

Thanks in advance! Sorry if this sounds like a stupid question, I'm quite new to programming and even newer to c++

**EDIT #1:**
Here is the code I have so far, it finds enteredName and then gets the 3 lines below:

```
if (myfile.is_open())
{
    while (getline(myfile, line))
    {
        if (line.compare(enteredName) == 0)
        {
            getline(myfile, line); //Password
            getline(myfile, line); //Account Number
            getline(myfile, line); //Balance
        }
    }
}
myfile.close();
```

Comment: Try writing something and ask a specific question if you get stuck.

Comment: @stark I have edited my post with my progress so far, I have found the line that I need to change but I can't figure out how to change it

Comment: Writing a file is not like manipulating it in an editor, so you can't "replace" a line because the rest of the file won't move if you increase/shorten the length of the line. You *can* overwrite fixed-size data, but the easiest way to do what you are trying to do is going to be to open a new output file and copy lines across.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code that solved my problem, it's a bit sloppy but it works!

It simply reads into a new file and makes any changes and then writes back again.

```
if (myfile.is_open())
{
    while (getline(myfile, line))
    {
        if (line.compare(enteredName) == 0)
        {
            tempFile << enteredName << "\n"; //Username
            getline(myfile, line);
            tempFile << line << "\n"; //Password
            getline(myfile, line);
            tempFile << line << "\n"; //Account Number
            getline(myfile, line);
            tempFile << newBal << "\n"; //Balance
        }
        else
        {
            tempFile << line << "\n"; //Username
            getline(myfile, line);
            tempFile << line << "\n"; //Password
            getline(myfile, line);
            tempFile << line << "\n"; //Account Number
            getline(myfile, line);
            tempFile << line << "\n"; //Balance
        }

    }
}
myfile.close();
tempFile.close();


/* Had to declare these again beacuse the compiler was throwing some bizarre error when using the old declarations */
ifstream tempF("TempStore.csv");
ofstream mainF("DataStore.csv", ios::trunc);

//Writes back from TempStore to DataStore with changes made correctly
if (tempF.is_open())
{
   while (getline(tempF, line))
   {
     mainF << line << "\n"; //Username
     getline(tempF, line);
     mainF << line << "\n"; //Password
     getline(tempF, line);
     mainF << line << "\n"; //Account Number
     getline(tempF, line);
     mainF << line << "\n"; //Balance
   }
}
tempF.close();
mainF.close();
```